# skin and snippet in eclipse PDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Is there a skin like textmate in eclipse pdt ? And also how to use snippet in eclipse ? for example if I want to insert full  to  including title,head,body etc. ALso how to make custom snippets ?

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse pdt they're called templates. Preferences->php->editor->templates

There should be a few already there you can take a look at.